# Command Line Tools update description of changes

Tags: macos, command-line, software-update

When Apple provides updates for OS X and other software it typically also describes the changes introduced in that version, as displayed in the App Store application's Updates tab or in a separate Apple knowledge base article.  However, when the "Command Line Tools" software (often installed by developers as part of [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)) is updated there typically is no list of changes.  This was also the case for the recent 6.4 update released on June 30th, 2015.  A web search for an Apple page that would list the changes does not seem to give any hits.

Is there any place, for example an Apple web page or knowledge base article, that lists the changes in Command Line Developer Tools updates?

There are many useful command-line tools in this package, so it would be interesting to know what new versions become available with each "Command Line Tools" update.

Comment: The command line tools only updates development tools which are part of Xcode (currently I think it is copy of ones in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr

Comment: Mark: Thanks for the comment. I clarified the question so that it is clearer that this refers to the development command-line tools.